# p4merge not working on git version 2.31.1

Tags: git, p4merge

My environment is: Centos Stream 9

I'm trying to use p4merge as diff tool but when I use:

git difftool --tool-help

I get:

```
'git difftool --tool=<tool>' may be set to one of the following:
                vimdiff
                vimdiff1
                vimdiff2
                vimdiff3

The following tools are valid, but not currently available:
                araxis
                bc
                bc3
                bc4
                codecompare
                deltawalker
                diffmerge
                diffuse
                ecmerge
                emerge
                examdiff
                guiffy
                gvimdiff
                gvimdiff1
                gvimdiff2
                gvimdiff3
                kdiff3
                kompare
                meld
                nvimdiff
                nvimdiff1
                nvimdiff2
                nvimdiff3
                opendiff
                smerge
                tkdiff
                winmerge
                xxdiff

Some of the tools listed above only work in a windowed
environment. If run in a terminal-only session, they will fail.
```

Ther is not p4merge entry.
I don't understand why, and how I can arrange it.

If you look at:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.31.1
You will see p4merge is in the possible options.

Do you know why or how it can be used?

Thanks

I want to use p4merge as difftool and diffmerge tool.

Comment: Do you have P4 (perforce) installed? p4merge is a tool that comes with P4. Git knows how to *run* it, but Git does not *come with* it.

Comment: Hi Torek, thanks for your response. Yes I have P4 installed. But as you can see is not one of the valid tools listed. I don't know why or how can I include in.

Comment: If running `type p4merge` shows it as runnable, it should be there in your list, right after `ecmerge`. I don't know why it's not listed. If `type p4merge` (in sh/bash) says `p4merge: not found`, that would explain the problem: it's either not installed, or not in your `$PATH`.